# Getting a sequential order with Asyncio

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio

Currently, I am doing a scrape of 60000 iterations on a page from an excel of URLs. For each url, I need to extract a set of data.

**Problem:** When I get the extraction, I have noticed that it mixes data from some rows with others, it repeats data and there are others that it does not extract.

**Doubt:** How can I get the data in order (Player 1, date 1, team 1/player 2, date2, team2...) and still use the asynchronous method? I need speed, so use asyncio.

```
async def getInfo_async(links: List[str]) -> list:
    res,tasks = [],[]
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        #session.mount("https://www.transfermarkt.com", gateway)
            for link in links:
                tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(getInfo(link, session)))
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                res.append(response)
    await asyncio.sleep((random.uniform(1,2.5)))
    return res
```

**EDIT 1**: I add a bit of the code for data extraction

```
def getInfo(link: str,session):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1,2.5))
    user_agent= ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36' ]
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent} 
    tree = session.get(link, headers=headers,timeout=120)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

    #Nombre jugador
    data_header_el = soup.find("h1", {"class": "data-header__headline-wrapper"})
```

**EDIT 2**: Actual Error:

```
File "XXXXXXXX", line 161, in getInfo_async
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(getInfo(link, session)))
  File "XXXXXXXX", line 41, in getInfo
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')
AttributeError: '_RequestContextManager' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Comment: You're mixing threads with asyncio, why? You can try [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/#client-example) (pure asyncio HTTP client/server library) and skip threads altogether.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've added some of the extraction code and changed the asynchronous method with what I've read from aiohttp. I get the error I put in EDIT

Comment: You should probably await the response: `html = await response.text()` and then use this `html` in `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`.